# Изменение высоты блока по мере прокрутки страницы

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть блок с фиксированными размерами. (600px x 1500px)

```css
.block {
  height: 1500px;
  background: #444;
  width: 600px;
  border: 5px solid red;
  position: relative;
  margin: 25px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
</div>
```

1 Вопрос: Как сделать, чтобы по мере прокрутки страницы на 4px вниз его высота уменьшалась на 3px.

2 Вопрос: Как сделать, чтобы чтобы при прокрутки на 800px вниз высота блока сразу изменялась с 1500px на 650px.

Вот тут небольшую заготовку для удобства накидал: https://jsfiddle.net/engenes/apug62bu/1/

…хочу на практике изучить изменение свойств элементов с прокруткой страницы.

Comment: Если на практике, то вам следует прикрепить код, который вы пытались написать, но у вас что-то не получилось. А то выглядит, будто вы  задание даете)

Comment: смотрите событие [onscroll](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onscroll)

Comment: да нет, речь не о задании, просто самому стало интересно. А код мне показался слишком плохим чтобы на общее обозрение его выставлять)

Comment: Не размещайте код на сторонних ресурсах вроде jsfiddle. Для таких случаев в редакторе есть специальный инструмент, кнопка в виде `<>` или `Ctrl + M`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Только вот из-за того, что скролл зависит от высоты содержимого страницы (а в вашем случае высоты блока) пример плохо отображает происходящее.

```js
var block = document.querySelector('.block');

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  var
    scroll = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
    height = scroll < 800 ? 1500 - Math.floor(scroll / 4 * 3) : 650;

  block.style.height = height + 'px';
  console.log(height);
});
```

```css
.block {
  height: 1500px;
  background: #444;
  width: 600px;
  border: 5px solid red;
  position: relative;
  margin: 25px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```

Comment: поместил содержимое вашего ответа сначала jsfiddle там скрипты не сработали. (закомментировал по очереди строки scroll height) при строке scroll ничего не происходит, при строке height блок сворачивается сразу к конечной высоте, не дождавшись прокрутки вниз на 800 px. Даже при увеличении исходной высоты блока до 2400px

Comment: Спасибо разобрался, все таки практика... потыкал и все переварилось)))